# How to use XMLStarlet to lookup values in a second file

Tags: xmlstarlet

Let's assume we have two directories:

```
/home/a
/home/b
```

In directory `a` with have lots of XML files like this:

```
<root>
  <id>87182378127381273</id>
  <name>just a name</name>
</root>
```

and for each of the `id` we find an XML file in directory `b`, like:

```
/home/b/87182378127381273.xml
...
```

and in that file we have for instance:

```
<root>
  <counter1>879</counter1>
</root>
```

And now I just want to run an xmlstarlet command that outputs the following for each found XML in directory `a`:

```
87182378127381273,just a name,879
...
```

I tried to solve this by this xmlstarlet command:

```
find . -iname '*.xml' | xargs xmlstarlet sel \
  -t -m "/root" -i "./id" -v "./id" -o -v "./name" -b -n | grep -v ^$
```

Now I wanted to use the `--var` option and load the second XML by constructing the file path with the value of `id` and output the timestamp value, but I don't know how. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer rewritten after question was rephrased.

This should do it:

```sh
# shellcheck  shell=sh  disable=SC2016
find '/home/a' -type f -iname '*.xml' -exec xmlstarlet select --text \
  -t -m 'root[string(id)]' \
       --var bpath='concat("/home/b/",id,".xml")' \
       --var ct='document($bpath)/root/counter1' \
       -v 'concat(id,",",name,",",$ct)' -n \
  {} +
```

- why not skip `xargs` when `find` can invoke a command with as many
  filenames (`{} +`) as the command line can hold and repeat as needed
- use an XPath [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#NT-PredicateExpr) to match a root
  element with a non-empty `id` child element,
  no output is generated if `root[string(id)]` isn't matched
- use the XSLT [`document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document) function to
  look up a value in an external XML file

  - if using a relative pathname with `document()` it must be relative
    to the directory in which `xmlstarlet` is invoked (i.e. the current directory)
  - if the target file is inaccessible `xmlstarlet` will issue a
    `failed to load external entity "…"` error message
- use the XPath [`concat`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#function-concat) function to stringify
  one record
- don't forget `select`'s `-T` (aka `--text`) option for plaintext
  output

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. And how would you insert the value of `/*[z:status="PUBLIC"]/z:id` into `"/path/ID.xml"` ?

Comment: somehow this looks like an ai-generated answer :-)

Comment: Tried it out, it just prints out nothing.

Comment: @basZero: Without access to the actual data my answer was meant as an outline. To take this further I need to know what data files and the lookup file look like. And I can assure you my answer isn't AI-generated (hint: look at the link in my SO profile).

Comment: i rephrased the question. I'm still not able to solve this with a single xmlstarlet command

Comment: @basZero: I updated my answer to reflect the rephrased question.

Comment: Thanks @urznow , that works fine! Is there a way to check if the 2nd file exists? I'd like to use a default value, if the 2nd file does not exist. Thanks for your solution! Marked.

Comment: @basZero: I'd append a 3rd variable `--var v --if 'string($ct)' -v '$ct' --else -o 'defaultvalue' -b -b` and use `$v` instead of `$ct` inside the following `concat(…)`. `xmlstarlet` has a global `--quiet` option to suppress any error messages but used with the `select` subcommand it's buggy and also suppresses output to `stdout` so you may also want to add `2>/dev/null` also.